# Is China Miéville still planning a return to Bas-Lag?

Tags: china-mieville, bas-lag

In his 2007 interview for [Dragon Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_(magazine)) Issue 352, China Miéville stated that after the critical/public response to *[Iron Council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Council)* he felt it was important to take a break from stories set in Bas-Lag but he'd be back there sooner rather than later nonetheless. That was now over a decade ago and *Iron Council* turns 17 this year. I for one have been looking forward to returning to life in the shadow of Perdido Street Station. So has China said anything to indicate that we're either not going to see any more tales from Bas-Lag after all or hinted that something new is coming or anything to give us some indication about where he's at in regard to his strange, terrible, beautiful creation?

Answer (score 5):

I have tried to find later instances of Miéville commenting on "Returning to Bas-Lag" - previously he has said that it is the most common question he encounters - but I have not been able to find anything later than 2013, just 6 years on from the Dragon Magazine interview. Miéville is still attending Q&A sessions at literary events, but I have not been able to find records of what was asked. If someone has attended one of these events in person, they may have a better idea!

The latest interview I have found is in a [Hungarian SF magazine](http://sfmag.hu/2013/04/30/china-mieville-interview/):

> SFmag.hu: You’ve become a well-known and recognized author with the
> Bas-Lag novels. Do you have any plans on returning to that world?
>
> China Miéville: Perhaps. But only if and when I can think of a story
> that necessitates returning, rather than going back just as a default.

This echos what he has previously said in interviews, for example at [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/interviews/show/38.China_Mi_ville) in 2009:

> GR: Any plans to write another novel set in Bas Lag?
>
> Sure. It's a setting I'm enormously proud of and happy with. But I'll
> only do it when the story is right and when I can write something
> without undermining the three previous books, in particular the ending
> of the last book. Which was the book that I know many readers didn't
> like nearly as much as the others, but remains my favorite of the
> three, and not—truly—just to be contrarian.

So as far as I can see, another Bas-Lag novel remains possible, but only if he comes up with a story which *requires* it. Just to mention another possibility, some believe that "[This Census Taker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Census-Taker)" (published in 2016) is actually set in Bas-Lag, although in truth it is hard to determine this clearly.